# Differences in using <iframe> and <embed> for displaying SVG and scripting

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, svg

I'm trying to create Dynamic SVG graphics, it is my understanding that the only way to create dynamic SVG is to use a scripting language, so I have a few questions, basically I'd like to load or embed the SVG to a HTML web page and control the graphics using Inputs in the web page, rather than hardcoding the ECMAscript in the SVG file. I'm not entirely sure if I should use the embed tag or an iframe for displaying the SVG here are my doubts regarding SVG and scripting:

1. Whats the difference (in terms of scripting) in using an `<iframe>` or and `<embed>` tag for accessing the SVG elements?, maybe someone can include simple examples.

   Can SVG evaluate math expressions in element attributes(just to be sure)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use either `<iframe>` or `<embed>`. Instead, embed your SVG directly in XHTML like so:
http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml

With that, you have full access to the SVG DOM as part of your document. As shown in that example, you simply need to be certain to create SVG elements (but not attributes) using the SVG namespace. You must also ensure that your web host is sending the content type for xhtml as `application/xhtml+xml` or `text/xml`, not `text/html`.

```
phrogz$ curl --silent -I http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml | grep "Type"
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml
```

*For more examples of JavaScript manipulating SVG mixed with HTML, see the various .xhtml files in [that same directory](http://phrogz.net/SVG). A particularly compelling example is [this one](http://phrogz.net/SVG/stirling_numbers.xhtml), which dynamically creates hundreds of small SVG files as inline elements flowing like text.*

And to your question:

> *Can SVG evaluate math expressions in element attributes(just to be sure)?*

Not in general, no. However, the usage of [SMIL Animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#AnimationElementsExample) does allow you to specify various interpolation methods of properties over time.

Finally, note that you don't have to put SVG in HTML to make it dynamic. You can script SVG with JavaScript directly. For example, see this test file (press the green button to start simulation):
http://phrogz.net/svg/SpringzTest.svg

Comment: Great answer, specifically for pointing out what the content type should be, I think I was mislead by the [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) as it say that they wish to be able to embed SVG markup directly into the HTML so I thought it couldn't be done that way.

Comment: Regarding W3 Schools, see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/). I seriously suggest that you click the link in your Google results that says "block all results from w3schools.com"

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that they have certain irregularities, but sometimes it s good for quick reference, although I'll rely on it far less.

Comment: May I ask, why do we have to use the `<![CDATA[]]>` tag? when placing scripts that manipulate the SVG

Comment: @Triztian In XML (of which XHTML is an application) a literal `<` character starts a tag. The less-than symbol in the following markup is invalid XML: `<script ...> for (var i=0;i<10;++i){ ... }</script>`. You must either remember to type `&lt;` and `&gt;` and `&amp;` in your scripts whenever you want just that character, or you can wrap it all in a CDATA block (and ensure you don't have the three characters `]]>` in your script anywhere).

Comment: Ohhh, I see, you mean the literal in the javascript code, thank you very much.

Comment: @Phrogz I tried your example (thank you for keeping it) on my website on a page called index.html and it also worked (FF, chrome & safari) I had to ditch the <![CDATA[ tag though but the path scripting still works. (www.stretchsketch.com)

Answer (score 1):

> *Whats the difference (in terms of scripting) in using an  or and  tag for accessing the SVG elements?, maybe someone can include simple examples.*

`<iframe>`:

> Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the same-origin policy, and cannot access most of the properties in the other window object if it was loaded from a different domain. This also applies to a script inside a frame trying to access its parent window. Cross-domain communication can still be achieved with window.postMessage.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting

We access iframe content by `iframe_element.contentWindow` method:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe id="SVG_frame" src="image.svg"></iframe>
  </body>
  <script>
    var SVG_frame = document.getElementById ( "SVG_frame" );
    var SVG_content = null;
    function getContent ()
    {
      SVG_content = SVG_frame.contentWindow;
      SVG_content ? alert ( "YAY!" ) : alert ( "BOO!" );
    }
      SVG_frame.onload = getContent;
  </script>
</html>
```

`<embed>`:

Example (view source): https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-embed.html

(both methods fail at least in Chromium)

`<object>`

Example (view source): https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-object.html

---

> Can SVG evaluate math expressions in
>   element attributes(just to be sure)?

like `<element attribute="48/2*(9+3)"/>`?

I did't find a word about it in [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/).

---

**EDIT**

Personally, I recommend to use `<object>` + [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and/or `object_element.contentDocument`. I've tested both in Chromium and Firefox.

AHA! `<object>` has similar security behavior to `<iframe>`: domain, protocol must be same for site and SVG file.

---

**EDIT2**

If You are interested how to get markup vector graphics to work in Internet Explorer(s) without plug-in(s), then [Vector Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VML) is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you mean with dynamic. In most cases yes, you'll probably want scripts. There's no difference if you put your script in the HTML or the SVG file, both will be executed by the same engine.

You can create interactive/animated svg content with the [declarative animation elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html) (aka SMIL). You can also do simple hover effects with CSS :hover rules, or transitions with [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).

XSLT can also be used to make somewhat dynamic svg content, since it can transform your input to something else. It doesn't cover the interaction aspect though.

You can access the svg elements from the HTML file that includes it with either of:

`theEmbeddingElement.contentDocument` (preferred, but doesn't work on `<embed>`)
or alternatively `theEmbeddingElement.getSVGDocument()`.

Comment: The purpose is not for animations, its just for rendering some technical drawings based on the the value of some inputs, so they won't change between seconds.