# click event on svg refuses to play

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I found this code at [codepen](https://codepen.io/daviddarnes/pen/waRVMm) and I tested on jsfiddle, on codepen but...when I add it to a localhost test page the click event doesn't do anything!

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">

    <!-- bar 1 -->
     <path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M0,0 L6,0 L6,16 L0,16 L0,0 Z" id="bar1">
      <animate xlink:href="#bar1"
               attributeName="d"
               from="M0,0 L6,0 L6,16 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
                to="M0,0 L6,3.20001221 L6,12.7999878 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
                fill="freeze" 
                begin="startAnimation.begin" />
      <animate xlink:href="#bar1"
               attributeName="d"
                from="M0,0 L6,3.20001221 L6,12.7999878 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
               to="M0,0 L6,0 L6,16 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
                fill="freeze" 
                begin="reverseAnimation.begin" />
    </path>

    <!-- horizontal line -->
     <path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M10,0 L16,0 L16,16 L10,16 Z" id="bar2">
      <animate attributeName="d"
                from="M10,0 L16,0 L16,16 L10,16 Z"
                to="M5.9944458,3.20001221 L15,8 L15,8 L5.9944458,12.7999878 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
               fill="freeze" 
               begin="startAnimation.begin" />
      <animate attributeName="d"
                from="M5.9944458,3.20001221 L15,8 L15,8 L5.9944458,12.7999878 Z"
                to="M10,0 L16,0 L16,16 L10,16 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
               fill="freeze" 
               begin="reverseAnimation.begin" />
    </path>
  
    <!--  controls -->
    <!-- these are on top of the visible icon. Their radius changes depending on which is active
    Opacity is set to 0 so you can't see them-->
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill-opacity="0">
      <animate dur="0.01s" id="startAnimation" attributeName="r" values="16; 0" fill="freeze" begin="click" />
      <animate dur="0.01s" attributeName="r" values="0; 16" fill="freeze" begin="reverseAnimation.end" />
    </circle>
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="0" fill-opacity="0">
      <animate dur="0.001s" id="reverseAnimation" attributeName="r" values="16; 0" fill="freeze" begin="click" />
      <animate dur="0.001s" attributeName="r" values="0; 16" begin="startAnimation.end"  fill="freeze"  />
    </circle>
  </svg>
```

Does anybody had experienced sth similar? 
I can't find what I do wrong here...

PS: I also added this style:

```
/*
 * Play
 * ----
 */
.play {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   top: 35%;
   left: 35%;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0.4em;
   width: 30%;
   height: 30%;
}
```

and modified the 1st line like

```
<svg class="play" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">
```

still with no result!

Comment: How are you loading your local test?

Comment: Does your localhost have an html declaration and the full html boilerplate? That's bitten me in the past

Comment: If you click the upper left corner of the icon the animation doesn't work. The solution would be increasing the radius of the circle and the correspondent values. (instead of 16 you may use 22.5) Since the icon is so small you may have clicked in the insensitive zone.

Comment: I load it with local Apache + php. My declaration "<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Test</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/plugins/....css"><script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/plugins/chai/chai.js"></script>...etc</head><body>...etc"

Comment: The blind spot can disappear with 30 instead of 16 at "circle" where values="16; 0" or values="0; 16"; thanks @enxaneta

Answer (score 0):

On codepen, if you change the view to look at *debug mode* it will open a new tab with a full screen view of the page.

View the source and you will see that the page contains the normal HTML head and body tags.

Sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test - YouTube Play Pause Button</title>
<style>
      body {
  background: #111;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  margin-top: 45vh;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body translate="no">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1">

    <!-- bar 1 -->
        <path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M0,0 L6,0 L6,16 L0,16 L0,0 Z" id="bar1">
      <animate xlink:href="#bar1"
               attributeName="d"
               from="M0,0 L6,0 L6,16 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
                to="M0,0 L6,3.20001221 L6,12.7999878 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
                   fill="freeze" 
                   begin="startAnimation.begin" />
      <animate xlink:href="#bar1"
               attributeName="d"
                from="M0,0 L6,3.20001221 L6,12.7999878 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
               to="M0,0 L6,0 L6,16 L0,16 L0,0 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
                   fill="freeze" 
                   begin="reverseAnimation.begin" />
    </path>

    <!-- horizontal line -->
        <path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M10,0 L16,0 L16,16 L10,16 Z" id="bar2">
      <animate attributeName="d"
                   from="M10,0 L16,0 L16,16 L10,16 Z"
                   to="M5.9944458,3.20001221 L15,8 L15,8 L5.9944458,12.7999878 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
               fill="freeze" 
               begin="startAnimation.begin" />
      <animate attributeName="d"
                   from="M5.9944458,3.20001221 L15,8 L15,8 L5.9944458,12.7999878 Z"
                   to="M10,0 L16,0 L16,16 L10,16 Z"
               dur="0.3s"
               fill="freeze" 
               begin="reverseAnimation.begin" />
    </path>

    <!--  controls -->
    <!-- these are on top of the visible icon. Their radius changes depending on which is active
    Opacity is set to 0 so you can't see them-->
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill-opacity="0">
      <animate dur="0.01s" id="startAnimation" attributeName="r" values="16; 0" fill="freeze" begin="click" />
      <animate dur="0.01s" attributeName="r" values="0; 16" fill="freeze" begin="reverseAnimation.end" />
    </circle>
    <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="0" fill-opacity="0">
      <animate dur="0.001s" id="reverseAnimation" attributeName="r" values="16; 0" fill="freeze" begin="click" />
      <animate dur="0.001s" attributeName="r" values="0; 16" begin="startAnimation.end"  fill="freeze"  />
    </circle>
  </svg>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: OK... 1) tested with live-server -> it works, 2) tested on an iframe in my page with the source code from codepen's debug -> it works, 3) tested on top of my slider (a project I make) it doesn't work! hmmmm....

Comment: I don't know about the iframe.   maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692037/differences-in-using-iframe-and-embed-for-displaying-svg-and-scripting

Comment: maybe it's not the time for svg yet...I decided to abandon it in favor of old css: https://codepen.io/centurianii/pen/GawxMW